# What is the fix for this yarn install error after app upgrade

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have a Nodejs app which is managed by npm and yarn. I get the the following error when running yarn install which I'm unable to get past. This setup was working for me before, however I know the libraries of the app were upgraded recently which might be causing the issue.
What is the fix needed in this case?

````
$ node -e 'console.log(`{"startTime":${Date.now()}}`)' > telemetry.json
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution
 inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning Pattern ["colour@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "C:\\Users\\brm\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-colour-0.7.1-9cb169917ec5d12c0736d3
e8685746df1cadf778-integrity\\node_modules\\colour" as pattern ["colour@~0.7.1"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
warning Pattern ["optjs@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "C:\\Users\\brm\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-optjs-3.2.2-69a6ce89c442a44403141ad2
f9b370bd5bb6f4ee-integrity\\node_modules\\optjs" as pattern ["optjs@~3.2.2"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
warning clarinet@0.12.0: The engine "firefox" appears to be invalid.
warning clarinet@0.12.0: The engine "chrome" appears to be invalid.
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > bootstrap@4.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.16.1".
warning " > ebayui-nav@0.0.10" has incorrect peer dependency "@ebay/skin@^9.0.0".
warning "@ebay/optimizer-plugin-inc > request-promise-native@1.0.9" has unmet peer dependency "request@^2.34".
warning "@ebay/optimizer-plugin-inc > request-promise-native > request-promise-core@1.1.4" has unmet peer dependency "request@^2.34".
warning "@ebay/service-ebay > @ebay/openapi-ebay > enjoi@6.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "@hapi/joi@^14.0.0".
warning "@babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.14.5" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.13.0".
warning "@babel/preset-env > @babel/plugin-proposal-class-static-block@7.14.5" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.12.0".
warning " > @babel/preset-es2015@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoped-functions@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-classes@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-destructuring@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-duplicate-keys@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-for-of@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-function-name@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-instanceof@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-literals@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-modules-amd@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-modules-systemjs@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-modules-umd@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-object-super@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-parameters@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-spread@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning "@babel/preset-es2015 > @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex@7.0.0-beta.53" has incorrect peer dependency "@babel/core@>=7.0.0-beta.50 <7.0.0-rc.0".
warning " > @storybook/addon-actions@3.4.12" has unmet peer dependency "@storybook/addons@^3.3.0".
warning " > @storybook/react@3.4.12" has unmet peer dependency "babel-runtime@>=6.0.0".
warning " > babel-loader@7.1.5" has incorrect peer dependency "babel-core@6".
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@10.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=5".
warning " > extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0".
warning " > glob-loader@0.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "glob@*".
warning " > react-test-renderer@17.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@17.0.2".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[6/17] ⠄ gc-stats
[8/17] ⠄ core-site-speed-ebay
[3/17] ⠄ grpc
[9/17] ⡀ uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
error C:\Users\brm\gitBRM\billui\node_modules\grpc: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\brm\gitBRM\billui\node_modules\grpc
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.5
node-pre-gyp info using node@12.16.1 | win32 | x64
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\brm\gitBRM\billui\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.11/node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! install request to https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.11/node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz failed, reason: self signed certificate in ce
rtificate chain
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.24.11 and node@12.16.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error request to https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.11/node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz failed, reason: self signed certificate in
certificate chain
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.16.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.16.1 | win32 | x64
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.1/node-v12.16.1-headers.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1473:34)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:916:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:686:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\brm\\gitBRM\\billui\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--
library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\brm\\gitBRM\\billui\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--modul
e_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\brm\\gitBRM\\billui\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=5" "--nod
e_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\brm\gitBRM\billui\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\brm\gitBRM\billui\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallbac
k-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\brm\gitBRM\billui\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_
name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\brm\gitBRM\billui\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --
napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\brm\gitBRM\billui\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\brm\\gitBRM\\billui\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--f
allback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\brm\gitBRM\billui\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.5
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\brm\gitBRM\billui\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_lib```
````

Comment: Looks like you're having issues with the VPN or the firewall connectivity. Try opening the browser and running https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.1/node-v12.16.1-headers.tar.gz and check if it downloads.